# Question about exercise 5.1 in TeXbook

Tags: tex-core, hyphenation, ligatures

The answer to the exercise states:

> TEX will reinsert the ff ligature by itself after hyphenating shelf{}ful.
> (Appendix H points out that ligatures are put into a hyphenated word that contains no
> “explicit kerns”

But the following example shows that ligature is reinserted even if the word is not hyphenated:

```
\hsize=70pt a shelf{}ful firefly
\end
```

[image]

Which rule in appendix H explains that?

---

But if the first word is not used, the ligature is not reinserted:

```
\hsize=70pt shelf{}ful firefly
\end
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the example file

```
\hsize=70pt a shelf{}ful firefly

\hsize=70pt shelf{}ful firefly
\end
```

Upon running TeX on it, we get on the terminal

```
Overfull \hbox (7.58342pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1--2
[]\tenrm a shelf-ful fire-|

Overfull \hbox (0.63898pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 3--4
[]\tenrm shelfful fire-|
```

You can notice that in the second case the symbolic representation is different and the reason is that TeX never tries hyphenation on a word fragment that's not preceded by glue. This restriction is not used in LuaTeX and, indeed, if we run LuaTeX on the same file we get

```
Overfull \hbox (7.58342pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1--2
[]\tenrm a shelf-ful fire-|

Overfull \hbox (0.36119pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 3--4
[]\tenrm shelf-ful fire-|
```

Once the word fragment has been subjected to trial hyphenation, ligatures are reconstituted. The TeXbook indeed recommends to use either the italic correction `\/` or another explicit kern, in order to break ligatures. In the case of `ff`, `\kern0pt` seems best with Computer Modern, but it may not be with another font.